# API call not working if including www in the URL

Tags: rest, no-www

I just migrated my web app from a server that was using Apache to a new server using Nginx. Everything is fine, except for my API routes.

I'm testing with POSTMAN, and if I use `https://www.example.com/api/example` I just get a response with an empty "message" variable.
But if I use `https://example.com/api/example`, it works fine.

I have a mobile app pointing to the URL which includes WWW, and I don't want to make an update just to make this change. How can I make the route including WWW work again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the host name in nginx config file to include www.

Sample:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I got the following warning:
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on [::]:443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: I also tried adding a different block using port 80 and www, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post your nginx config

Comment: I'm using Laravel Forge, so I ended up updating my domain in the Meta > Domain section to include www.

Comment: Oh, but I thought this problem only occurs since you change from apache to nginx.